# MySQL alter event inside trigger fails with a weird message

Tags: mysql, events, triggers

I have a trigger similar to this

```
create trigger myTrigger after insert on myTable for each row
alter event myEvent enable;
```

which fails on creation with the message

> #1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.

What is the connection between event and commit?

Comment: See [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) and [13.3.3 Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).